# Why is Loadcontent already executed inside Initialize() method?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying out XNA / Monogame in Visual Studio. I find the documentation somewhat lacking in explaining how the main XNA structure operates. As I understand it, Game1.Initialize() gets called before Game1.LoadContent().

But in this code example, I have found that the Content actually IS already loaded when still inside the initialize function. In this code example you will see that **"---1---"** gets logged in the console BEFORE **"---2---"**. Why is this?

**GAME1.CS**

```
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            // SOMEHOW LOADCONTENT HAS NOW ALREADY BEEN EXECUTED?
            Console.WriteLine("----2---- STILL EXECUTING INIT CODE");
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----1---- GAME1 LOADS CONTENT");
            AssetsManager.LoadContent(this);
            SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        }
```

**Console output:**

```
----1---- GAME1 LOADS CONTENT
----2---- STILL EXECUTING INIT CODE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you call `base.Initialize()` at the beginning of the method, which then calls the `LoadContent` method. calls to base class implementations (including `base.Initialize()` and `base.LoadContent()`) should allways be at the end of the according method.

Comment: Yes, I found that out by trial and error. But how could I have known this? The documentation does not state that base.initialize() actually calls loadcontent(). When you click "go to definition" in the editor, there is still no indication whatthe base class does (the method is empty). It seems a bit spaghetti-code to me....

Comment: 'goto' is spaghetti code. The reason you cannot see this is because visual studios "go to definition" doesn't decompile the code, so the method is empty. VS merely shows the class structure. On a related note, if you find this annoying (even though it's nothing more than a 2 minutes testing issue), then I'm gonna guess you wont find the open-source community very friendly. Most stuff, while well documented, usually doesn't cover EVERY scenario. Hence, the open-source part.

Comment: I think the main problem with XNA/Monogame is that it seems to be a 'dead' project and the documentation is very sparse (if you can find it). I still use it for tutorial purposes, but unlike Unity or Javascript, there is not really a living breathing online community that keeps inventing cool new stuff every week.

Comment: @Kokodoko Agreed.  My two favourite tutorial sites Reimers (MVP); and Shawn Hargreaves (Microsoft) stopped some years ago.  I gave up on it when it was announced it would not be supported by Win8.  I switched to Unity and have not looked back